# How to avoid duplicates in Visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have created a lookup field and ADD button in VF page when user select lookup(PO Custom object) and hit add button, lookup fields values are display in pageblocktable .Once again i hit a button values are added in pageblocktable. How to avoid duplicate in pageblocktable.

```
public PageReference addPO(){
    showSection5=true;   
    List<PO__c> poDetails = [Select Id,Name,Container_Number__c,Event_Number__c,Source_of_Supply__c,Order_Type__c,Season_Code__c,Number_Pallets_Cartons__c,Department_Team__r.Name  from PO__c where Id =: keycode.PO__c ];
    for(PO__c poLineItem:poDetails){
        wrapperPO wsinglePO = new wrapperPO();     
        wsinglePO.poID = poLineItem.Id;
        wsinglePO.poName = poLineItem.Name;
        wsinglePO.poContainer=poLineItem.Container_Number__c;
        wsinglePO.poEventnumber =poLineItem.Event_Number__c;
        wsinglePO.poSourceSupply=poLineItem.Source_of_Supply__c;     
        wsinglePO.poOtype=poLineItem.Order_Type__c; 
        wsinglePO.poSeasonCode=poLineItem.Season_Code__c; 
        wsinglePO.poNumberPallets=poLineItem.Number_Pallets_Cartons__c;
        wsinglePO.poBuyer=poLineItem.Department_Team__r.Name;
        wPO.add(wsinglePO);
    }
    return null;
  }

<apex:commandButton value="Add PO" action="{!addPO}" reRender="block" style="margin-left:100px" /> 
  <apex:pageBlockSection id="poLineItemdetails" rendered="{!showSection5}" >
       <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!wPO}" var="poLine" id="newItems" >        
       <apex:column value="{!poLine.poName}" title="PO Number" headerValue="PO Number"/>
       <apex:column value="{!poLine.poBuyer}" title="Buyer" headerValue="Buyer"/>
       <apex:column value="{!poLine.poContainer}" title="Container Number" headerValue="Container Number" />        
       <apex:column value="{!poLine.poEventnumber}" title="Event Number" headerValue="Event Number" />
       <apex:column value="{!poLine.poSourceSupply}" title="Source Supply" headerValue="Source Supply" />
       <apex:column value="{!poLine.poOtype}" title="Order Type" headerValue="Order Type" />
       <apex:column value="{!poLine.poSeasonCode}" title="Season Code" headerValue="Season Code" />        
       <apex:column value="{!poLine.poNumberPallets}" title="Number Pallets" headerValue="Number Pallets" />    
        <apex:column width="5%">
        <apex:commandButton action="{!removeNewObject}" value=" Remove " reRender="newItems,panelWithVar">
            <apex:param name="p1" value="{!rowNumber}" assignTo="{!numberOfRowToRemove}"/>
        </apex:commandButton>
    </apex:column>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
     </apex:pageBlockSection>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by two ways

First Way:-

```
Maintain you wrapperPO instace in map then eg:- Map<id,wrapperPO> MapOfwrapperPO.

private Map<id,wrapperPO> MapOfwrapperPO = new Map<id,wrapperPO>();
public PageReference addPO()
{
    showSection5=true;   
    List<PO__c> poDetails = [Select Id,Name,Container_Number__c,Event_Number__c,Source_of_Supply__c,Order_Type__c,Season_Code__c,Number_Pallets_Cartons__c,Department_Team__r.Name  from PO__c where Id =: keycode.PO__c ];
    for(PO__c poLineItem:poDetails){
        wrapperPO wsinglePO = new wrapperPO();     
        wsinglePO.poID = poLineItem.Id;
        wsinglePO.poName = poLineItem.Name;
        wsinglePO.poContainer=poLineItem.Container_Number__c;
        wsinglePO.poEventnumber =poLineItem.Event_Number__c;
        wsinglePO.poSourceSupply=poLineItem.Source_of_Supply__c;     
        wsinglePO.poOtype=poLineItem.Order_Type__c; 
        wsinglePO.poSeasonCode=poLineItem.Season_Code__c; 
        wsinglePO.poNumberPallets=poLineItem.Number_Pallets_Cartons__c;
        wsinglePO.poBuyer=poLineItem.Department_Team__r.Name;
        //wPO.add(wsinglePO);
        MapOfwrapperPO.put(poLineItem.Id,wsinglePO); 

}
    if(MapOfwrapperPO.size()>0)
    wPO = MapOfwrapperPO.values(); 
    return null;
  }
```

**Second way:**

Maintain set of id where you need to maintain the id of record which already are selected by user and when user select same lookup and hit the button then you need to check the selected value in look (id of lookup field) already present in the set (which we have created to store selected record) or not. If id present then you can show a message record alread exist.You can do this thing at server side or at client side.

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you very much D-Horse. Your code is working fine for me. But when we try to add 1 or more records the table order will be changed. For example, I have added PO A in the table then I go and select PO B and add it to table.Again I go and select some other PO new and add it to table now the PO new record should be added first row in the table. But the record will be added irregular order. Can you please guide me on this?

Answer (score 1):

Clear the `wPO` list at the very beginning of your action method.

```
public PageReference addPO(){
    showSection5=true;   
    List<PO__c> poDetails = [Select Id,Name,Container_Number__c,Event_Number__c,Source_of_Supply__c,Order_Type__c,Season_Code__c,Number_Pallets_Cartons__c,Department_Team__r.Name  from PO__c where Id =: keycode.PO__c ];
    if(!wPO.isEmpty()){
        wPO.clear();
    }
    for(PO__c poLineItem:poDetails){
        wrapperPO wsinglePO = new wrapperPO();
        //your stuff

        wPO.add(wsinglePO);
    }
}
```

Comment: If we clear the WPO list then how he will show two records in table.

Comment: list need to be re populated with the required entries only. I have edited the answer

Comment: Suppose I've entered val in field like "A" and hit the button.According to your code the wpo list will clear(if there is already any item in list) and then fetch the record and add in the list, that rec will populate on page,now I want to select another record to populate on page so I enter "B" in field in hit the button now according to your code the list will cleared and my item which was related to "A" lost and lst only contain "B".if user doesn't want to show pervious record in that case your code is good, user can also this by only single instance without maintaining list.

Comment: agreed @D-Horse. In that case I prefer your answer

Comment: It's always pleasure to contribute something I have to the community